# How can I tell which partition is my Linux install?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, pop-os

So I am trying to install Pop!_OS over a broken Ubuntu install.  My machine has 2 identical 2TB NVME drives, and the Pop installer is allowing me to choose between them.

One drive has 2 partitions (536.9 fat32 & 2TB ext4) and the other drive has 6 partitions - a mix of fat32 and ntfs.

Is there any way to tell which one is the windows and which is the Ubuntu partition?  I also have access to the terminal if that helps.

Comment: Linux can't be installed in NTFS partitions and a small FAT32 partition is usually the ESP (EFI System Partition). It really shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one holding [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), a Windows file system, should be disk the Windows disk with the Windows partitions.

The one holding [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), a Linux files system, should be the Linux disk and as there's only one ext4, this should be the Ubuntu partition you want to nuke. The fat32 is most possibly the boot partition from Ubuntu and could be re-used as Pop OS boot partition.

To verify this, you could switch to a command line and inspect the partitions contents. I don't know for sure, if PopOS installer includes a command line, but booting to a [LiveImage](https://support.system76.com/articles/pop-live-disk/)